# I trying to establish a relation between 2 tables via LARAVEL-MIGRATIONS, but 'm getting this error. How can I fix?

Tags: php, laravel

I created two tables, and stablished a relationship between them, but I get an error when migrating. what should I do?

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('vendas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_vendas');
            /*FOREIGN ATRIBURE FROM TABLE USERS*/
            $table->bigInteger('cliente');
            $table->string('produto', 100);
            $table->timestamps();
//
            /*REFENCING FOREIGN KEY*/
            $table->foreign('cliente')->references('id_cliente')->on('teste');
//
        });
    }

//AND THIS:

    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('teste', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id_cliente');
                $table->string('nome_cliente');
                $table->boolean('estado');
                $table->text('obs');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to match the FK item to the related table field exactly.  In this case, add unsigned to the `cliente` field on the `vendas` table.

```
 $table->bigInteger('cliente')->unsigned();
```

Also, you didn't note which error you are receiving, but Laravel out of the box is looking for the model-name-id on its relationships.  E.g. `cliente_id` on a model called **Cliente**.  If you are not going to include this, you will need to make note of this in the relationship method.

Comment: now i'm getting this error:

 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`#sql-548_1b6` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `vendas` add constraint `vendas_cliente_foreign` foreign key (`cliente`) references `teste` (`id_cliente`))

Comment: OK, then the other part of the error is that you are creating vendas before teste, which means that when there is no table to make a FK from, it fails.  Create teste BEFORE vendas and this should work now.

Comment: so how can I alter the execution order? 
I am just going to the terminal and write the following command: php artisan migrate

Comment: Laravel executes the migrations in the order of the files in the folder, which usually start with the date in the name of the file.  Change the date of the `teste` table on the file name to earlier than the name on the `vendas` table migration.  OR, if you have both of these in the same file, like in the question you wrote, just move the function that creates `teste` ABOVE the one that creates `vendas`

Comment: I created 'em on sepated files... i did it and still getting the error: (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
maybr i should consider and check the documentary

Comment: Yep checking docs is always good.  If on separate files, just make sure that `teste` is firing first (alpha or date order by the name of the migration file).  And that you have wiped the old migration (wiped database) first.

Comment: man, your tips was right,IT WORKED!!! I was adding the unsigned() on the PK of the referenced table instead of adding on the collumn to be referenced! LOL thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code

```
        $table->bigInteger('cliente');
```

To

```
       $table->bigInteger('cliente')->unsigned();
```

The reason for that is bigincrements create unsigned column so we need unsigned column while referencing it also

Comment: NOW I GET THIS ERROR:
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`#sql-548_1b6` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `vendas` add constraint `vendas_cliente_foreign` foreign key (`cliente`) references `teste` (`id_cliente`))

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted the error it could have given more clearance of the problem.
You are trying to attach a foreign key to a table which isn't created yet. The workaround is to disable and enable the foreign key check
Before migration

```
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

After migration

```
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Try this

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::create('vendas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_vendas');
            /*FOREIGN ATRIBURE FROM TABLE USERS*/
            $table->bigInteger('cliente');
            $table->string('produto', 100);
            $table->timestamps();
//
            /*REFENCING FOREIGN KEY*/
            $table->foreign('cliente')->references('id_cliente')->on('teste');
//
        });
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get an error. because auto-increment fields are automatically unsigned. this is while your foreign keys are not unsigned. just add ->unsigned() when you are defining the 'cliente' field. 
Also you should create the the 'teste' table before the 'vendas' table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('vendas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id_vendas');
        /*FOREIGN ATRIBURE FROM TABLE USERS*/
        $table->bigInteger('cliente')->unsigned(); // the only modification you need
        $table->string('produto', 100);
        $table->timestamps();

        /*REFENCING FOREIGN KEY*/
        $table->foreign('cliente')->references('id_cliente')->on('teste');
    });
}
```